# Wrong value displaying. With 'EntitySubscription' in Chatter

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, chatter, jquery

Im using the following code to return the list of users that I am following in Chatter. I am following 4 users.

```
    List<EntitySubscription> followers;

    followers = [
      SELECT Id, ParentId, Subscriber.Name, Parent.Name
      FROM EntitySubscription WHERE SubscriberId = :userId
    ];

    public List<EntitySubscription> getFollowers() {
       return followers;
    }
```

and then in my JS I put it in a div.

```
$("#myDiv").html('{! Followers}');
```

At the moment, all that displays is the following:

```
[0E8R0000000SD6KAM, 0E8R000000008DEAY, 0E8R00000004FZWE5, 0E8R000000008eVG1Q]
```

How do I get the user names to display instead of these numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an ***apex:repeat*** tag to accomplish this.  You can use apex repeat tags within scripts.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Followers}" var="f">
    $("#myDiv").append('{!f.Parent.Name}');
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Cheers Dunc44! That worked perfectly! I spent hours trying to figure that out.

Comment: Glad to here it.  No prob